# Map Blog pages to different custom URLs

Tags: blogger, blog, url, domain

I have a subdomain currently pointing towards a blog I write on Blogger.

I would like to add a new page to this blog and **point an entirely separate subdomain to that page.**

So, given that `status.mysite.com` points to the main page, how can I get `blog.mysite.com` to point to page 2?

Answer (score 1):

If your server is apache you can go for solution like mod_rewrite with declarations like these :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} blog\.mysite\.com
RewriteRule . /page2
```

And in your domain name zone, `blog.mysite.com` is just an alias of `status.mysite.com`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in Google Blogger, then either your server is not Apache, or it is but you cannot get to it to do things like the previous suggestion.

Can you clarify why you want to do what you've described? What is the relationship between the new page and the rest of the blog?

Also, do you really want to point a separate subdomain to the at page (i.e. anyone who visits the subdomain is re-directed to the page inside your blog)? Or to have the page avaiable under its own access at the separate subdomain?

What benefits are you hoping to achieve by doing this rather than making a new blog, and using the entirely different sub-domain for it?